# Can I monitor network traffic and usage as a client?

Tags: networking

My computer, as well as other computers, is connected to one router. Can I monitor the traffic as a client, or only if my computer is connected between the modem and the router? Will other computer on the same router or network put up a firewall that can restrict the monitoring?

Answer (score 1):

In the general case you can only do it if your computer is between the router and clients (ie acting as a router) or, to a limited extent between the modem and the router (if the router does NAT you won't be able to tell which client is sending traffic).

There are some exceptions - If you are using a hub (not common anymore) or have a monitoring port on the router which mirrors a copy of all traffic you will be able to monitor the data from the PC as well.

Answer (score 0):

If your router is advanced enough, you might be able to check all traffic there. My router has Gargoyle on it and I can see the individual traffic of every device on my network from any computer on the network.

And no, if your router is keeping records then it knows what's going on with every device connected to it. A system's firewall cannot stop the router from keeping track of that system's network usage if it connected and using that router.